# Mouse movement using Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

In a particular scenario in my project I have to select some region of the map using a mouse. Below is the image.

How can I perform this using Protractor? This is the portion of the map:

[image: this is the portion of the map]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using [`actions`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions). You can move the mouse between elements, or offsets. Here's a general example:

```
browser.actions().
    mouseDown(element1).
    mouseMove(element2, {x: 42, y: 42}). // offset right/down
    mouseUp().
    perform();
```

Comment: Thanks @ Brine i will try this and let you know but i am not sure how to pass element 1 and 2 as when i try to find the locator strategy over map it reflects complete map not a portion of the map

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to act how you act physically. If you want to use keyboard, you can definitely use this.

This is in case if you wanna make 2 keywords. I used it for right click.

**element.sendKeys(protractor_1.Key.chord(protractor_1.Key.SHIFT, protractor_1.Key.F10));**

Thanks.